# Function Structure vs Unit Testing Private Function

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phpunit

I have a function, which someone else wrote, that creates a cURL wrapper object inside the function. Simplified version below

```
public function getCodes()
{
    //do some stufff

    $communicator = new Communicator();
    $result = $communicator->call($this->API_KEY);

    //do some stuff with $result
}
```

I was tasked with learning PHPUnit and writing tests for this type of code. In doing so I found that it's really hard to test a function like this when the object is created inside of the function and also that tests shouldn't require any outside communication to work.

We wanted to push our tests to git as many projects do but we didn't want to accidentally or intentionally push our API credentials to git.

So my solution was to keep getCodes() public but make it a wrapper for a private function that accepts a Communicator object as a parameter. Then I could test the private method with a mock Communicator object.

But this would mean that getCodes is never tested (my boss wants 100% code coverage) and I also read that you shouldn't be writing tests for private functions in most circumstances.

So my question is basically, how do I write a test for a function like this with an API call.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your solution. The code is tested, isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes but I don't want to be implementing a hack if I don't need to or if there's a better way.

Comment: Is it really a hack. You restructured your code, and the new code makes sense, design-wise.

Comment: 100% code coverage - including the most trivial method of one liner? well...

Comment: Yeah, I wrote tests for getters and setters :( it was kinda a learning experience though

Comment: fine - go full DI then. Your boss is paying you regardless:)

Comment: agree with @bayou.io seriously your boss need more insight into what code coverage really means. Also avoid Unit Testing private functions. The methods are private for a reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. My boss and I are both new to this whole TDD stuff but we're trying to do things the "right" way. I found some information on setting environment variables in Travis CI and ways to implement it with PHPunit also. I'll try using that to include the credentials and test the public function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really suggest rewriting the code to inject the Communicator object via constructor.
If you already see there is a big issue with writing tests for something it is a very strong signal to re-thing the current implementation.

Another thing is that you shouldn't test your privates. Sebastian Bergmann wrote a post on his blog about this some time ago and the conclusion is - it is possible just not good (https://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html).

Completely different thing is that I think your tests shouldn't go outside of the boundaries of your system. That is - mock everything that connects to outside systems. Such tests may fail for various of reasons non of witch are valid from the sole perspective of running tests.

You also mentioned coverage. Unfortunately this is something where, I hope, everyone will agree - you cannot have it the moment you start using native PHP resources (with some small exception like FS). You have to understand that things like curl, ssh, ftp and so on cannot be unit tested.